# How to get ip of sender in TCP in Java?

Tags: android, tcp

How to get ip of sender in TCP communication in Android.

any one have idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to receive tcp communication in android, you'll need to have done something like this:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

You can then get the address of the client from it's socket by

```
    InetAddress clientAddress = clientSocket.getInetAddress()
```

To get it in text form, you can then use

```
    String clientAddressString = clientAddress.getHostAddress()
```

Of course most of these things can throw exceptions, so you'll need to handle them.